# Prototype for patenting

Tags: patentability

Do I need to build a prototype for patenting something **in Europe**? I know that in USA you don't need it, but would like to know what is the case in Europe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request for grant of a European Patent includes a prescribed request form and elaboration of a patent application. The patent application may or may not contain claims, but later on you have to provide claims. These can be filed subsequently within the prescribed term. A prototype has not to be presented. By filing European patent applications it has to be paid attention if national laws of the state in which the applicant has his domicile or residence prescribes the filing via internal offices.